# REP bug or something else?

Tags: discussion

How is [This](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5938037/gopal-setty) user having 6 Reputation?

He has just one post with a score of -7 (7 downvotes). Still his reputation is more than 1. How?

Comment: There is a +1 on that post so that gives that user + 5 reputation. Reputation never gets negative

Comment: Well, linking this on Meta will quickly solve the problem...

Comment: and what about -7 ? Thats not counted?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: The question linked is about *old folk* This question is about a new user

Answer (score 6):

If the single upvote came after the question was downvoted several times, the 5 points rep will be awarded to the OP.

Comment: Is it a bug or SO rule? Because I think downvotes should be counted after the post get an upvote.

Comment: @SKD It's not a bug. The user can't fall below 1 rep.

Comment: I am not saying they should fall below 1 rep. But a user should remain on 1 rep untill he gets sufficient upvotes to clear all the prev downvotes.

Comment: @SKD Well, it's just not calculated like this.

Comment: @SKD _"I am not saying they should fall below 1 rep. But a user should remain on 1 rep untill he gets sufficient upvotes to clear all the prev downvotes."_ That _would_ be falling below 1 rep, even if it's never displayed as less than one. Either you think rep should fall below 1, behind the scenes or not, or you don't and the system works properly by _not_ making the rep less than one behind the scenes.